# Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm going through Mattan Griffel's "One Month Rails" (http://onemonthrails.com/) class. I'm trying to use the paperclip gem to upload images. Initial install and usage went fine, until he added a line to reduce the size of images. This was placed in app/models/pin.rb as shown in his tutorial:

```
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>" }
```

It worked until the styles: {} part was added. I have also updated my partial to pass in the :medium method.

I'm using:  paperclip (3.4.1),cocaine (0.5.1) and rails (3.2.12). I have seen other posts where this was fixed with homebrew, but I'm on a Windows 7 machine and I'm fairly certain that doesn't apply. Let me know if I need to post anything else.

Comment: Even i had same issue(m using Ubuntu), i did lot of search but didn't get any solution so just removed styles (has_attached_file :image ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm following the same course. After several gem changes (trying older versions of cocaine, etcetera...) the thing that solved my problem was adding this line to pin.rb:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16'
```

before  `belongs_to :user`

(change the path for your image magick install path)

After this, run a bundle update and reset your rails server.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16'
```

to this file.

`\config\environments\development.rb`

Make sure to run

```
which convert
```

so you know what version number and don't copy and paste another version number.

Restart your rails server

Answer (score 0):

Though it showed the path when I ran `which convert`, I download the ImageMagick and installed it separately and gave the path and added the line as mentioned by q256 and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I was using version `6.7.9` of ImageMagick. So in addition to adding the command_path, I had to update to the latest version of ImageMagick i.e `6.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on q256's answer, updating this file might cause it to break on heroku when you do a push, because the live-on-the-internet server won't know how to find a program installed on your local hard drive.

The more correct way (at least that I have found) to fix this issue for windows users is to update the development.rb file under config->environments->development.rb and throw the line in at the end of the file.

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16'
```

Hope that helps someone, and don't forget to restart your rails server after saving the file, note that a bundle update isn't required.